# IIS is not honoring the trailing slash in a redirect

Tags: iis, http, redirect

I've configured a redirect to point from anything in the root directory to `/racktables/`. When I actually go to `http://host/`, however, I am redirected to `http://host/racktables`, which, of course, redirects back to `http://host/racktables` ad infinitum.

Entry from web.config: `<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/racktables/" exactDestination="true" childOnly="true" />`

Is it possible to get IIS to honor this redirect exactly, or will I have to create a redirect in the default document at the root of the site? It seems like that would be a fairly significant oversight on Microsoft's part.

Comment: Are you using the URL Rewrite Module?

Comment: I'm using the HTTP Redirect module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the URL Rewrite Module it has some default rules to enforce or change the URL.  Two of them that I know about are converting the entire URL to lowercase and another appends a trailing slash to all non-file requests.  They are there primarily for SEO purposes but combined with what you have might "replace" or compliment your current setup.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and solved it by setting the redirect target to (e.g.) `http://host/racktables/#`. IIS didn't strip off my otherwise useless `#` and it kept the `/`.

As long as your web application doesn't choke on the empty hash, it should work for you, too.